# Why is an empty string assigned to a variable "text" first and only then is the entered value assigned?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I see that using the "hasNextInt()" method assigns an empty string to a variable "text" first and only then the entered value. Why is that?

Input:

> 15
> enter

Output:

> 15
>
> false
> 15
> enter
> true

Need output:

> 15
> enter
> true

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner cons = new Scanner(System.in);
        String enter = "enter";
        int summa = 0;
        boolean isEnter = false;
        while (!isEnter){
            if(cons.hasNextInt()){
                summa = summa + cons.nextInt();
            }
            else {
                String text = cons.nextLine();
                isEnter = enter.equals(text);
                System.out.println(summa);
                System.out.println(text);
                System.out.println(isEnter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```